# IOS Tab bar icon do not auto fill inside tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

My tab bar have 5 item, I want to each item have size equal 1/5 size of tab bar like image below (image design):

[image]

Tab bar items have not title, title is inside image (I not set title for viewControllers of tab bar items, only set navigationItem.title). I tried with other size of items (60x60; 120x120 and 96x64; 144x96) but it still very small. Image below is tab bar in my current app:

[image]

And my code in UITabBarController class (image and selected image setting in storyboard):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0 green:67/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1];

    for (UITabBarItem *tbi in self.tabBar.items) {
        tbi.image = [tbi.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        tbi.selectedImage = [tbi.selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        tbi.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.0, 0.0, -6.0, 0.0);
    }
}
```

Please help me to config tab bar items same as my design (the first image).

Thank so much!

Comment: Check the image insets of tab bar icon through storyboard.

Comment: I checked it and edit insets but not working,  insets of tab bar icon is (0,0,0,0)